# How to use a regex to match the string <div><span>regular</span><span>expression</span></div>

Tags: javascript, regex

1. How to use a regular expression to match this string:
   `<div><span>regular</span><span>expression</span></div>`.
2. How to  exchange  the first span of the contents and the contents of the second span.

In my opinion, it can use jquery source code.

Comment: show your attempts....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a nice tool to test regexps online: http://www.regexr.com/39d2p. You should first try by yourself before asking on Stack Overflow, so that you can provide what you tried and what did not work. Hint: jQuery won't be necessary for this job ;)

Comment: Match that string exactly? Your question needs more details.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Then the solution to you problem would be:

```
var str = '<div><span>regular</span><span>expression</span></div>';

var newString = 
    str.replace(
        /(<div><span>)([^<]*)(<\/span><span>)([^<]*)(<\/span><\/div>)/i,
        '$1$4$3$2$5'
); // where /[^<]*/ matches anything but '<'

// results in "<div><span>expression</span><span>regular</span></div>"
```

Whitespace-safe regex:

```
/(<\s*div\s*>\s*<\s*span\s*>)([^<]*)(<\/\s*span\s*>\s*<\s*span\s*>)([^<]*)(<\/\s*span\s*>\s*<\/\s*div\s*>)/i
```

But honestly this is just a vague answer to you vague question and might need a **[bit more jQuery :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)**

Comment: More generic would be `str.replace(/(<div><span>)([^<]+)(<\/span><span>)([^<]+)(<\/span><\/div>)/,'$1$4$3$2$5')`

Comment: Thank you @e666, I overlooked that they have to be swapped and not exchanged + the idea of not hardcoding the values. Updated answer